SSH2 SFTP Catch Uncaught Exception: Unable to start subsystem
The following code sends a file from S3 to an SFTP server. Overall it works, but in the event of a network connection problem I would like to catch the error that is thrown. I have tried to use .on() and try...catch.
import { Client, SFTPWrapper } from "ssh2";
import { S3 } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";
const s3Client = new S3({});
    await new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
                    const file = await s3Client.getObject({
                        Bucket: sourceBucket,
                        Key: sourceKey
                    });
                    const readStream = new Readable();
                    readStream.push(await file.Body!.transformToByteArray());
                    readStream.push(null);
        
                    const destinationFilePath = `${path}${sourceKey.split("/").pop()}`;
                    const client = new Client();
                    client
                        .on("ready", () => {
                            client.sftp((err: Error | undefined, sftp: SFTPWrapper) => {
                                if (err) reject (err);
                                const writeStream = sftp?.createWriteStream(destinationFilePath);
        
                                readStream?.pipe(writeStream);
                                writeStream.on("close", () => {
                                    sftp.end();
                                    client.end();
                                    resolve("Success");
        
                                }).on("error", (err: string | undefined) => {
                                    reject (err);
                                });
                            });
                        })
                        .connect({
                            host,
                            port,
                            username: userId,
                            password: SecretString
                        })
                        .on("error", (err) => {
                            reject (err);
                        });
                });

Here is example of an uncaught error that I have seen:

"Error: Unable to start subsystem: sftp"


I've try to simplify this code as I could for better understanding, but I didn't test it.
Note: It seems like your using typescript. If so. Please avoid overwriting types in fnc/methods. Instead search for packing type online (like @types/ssh2) otherwise write yours in d.ts (declaration file)
import { Client } from "ssh2";
import { S3 } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";

const s3Client = new S3({});
const client = new Client();

// create a fnc to get aws s3 obj
const getObjectFnc = async () => s3Client.getObject({
    Bucket: "sourceBucket",
    Key: "sourceKey"
});

// promise for connection 
const connection = (readStream) =>  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   return client.on("ready", () => {
        client.sftp((err, sftp) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            const destinationFilePath = `${path}${sourceKey.split("/").pop()}`;
            const writeStream = sftp.createWriteStream(destinationFilePath);
            readStream.pipe(writeStream);
            writeStream.on("close", () => {
                sftp.end();
                client.end();
                resolve("Success");
            }).on("error", err => {
                reject("Error at writeStream: " + err);
            });
        }).on("error", err => {
            reject("Error at sftp: " + err);
        });
    }).connect({
        host,
        port,
        username: userId,
        password: SecretString
    })
    .on("error", (err) => {
        reject("Error at client: " + err);
    });
});


// IIFE to avoid new promises chaning 
    (async () => {
        const readStream = new Readable(); // since iife can't be outside of the chain

        const file = await getObjectFnc();
        const arrTmp = await file.Body.transformToByteArray()

        readStream.push(arrTmp || null);
        await connection(readStream);
    })();


IDE reports "Cannot find name 'readStream'"

I apologize  for that mistake. It seems like we forgot to declare the "readStream" inside the connection promise.
Although, we can pass it as a reference value.
change the followings
await connection(readStream );
const connection = (readStream) =>  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {}
I beleive your be able to catch the readStream down there, otherwise let me know to setup the env and use different aproach
